# How to impose normalization condition (not initial condition) on DSolve or NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a set of differential equations (or DAEs):
$\begin{cases} 5x_{2} + 3x_{4} + 3x_{5} = \frac{dx_{1}}{dt}\\ 5x_{1} + 5x_{2} + 5x_{3} + 3x_{4} + x_{5}= 0\\ 3x_{2} + 3x_{4} + 10x_{5} = \frac{dx_{3}}{dt}\\x_{1} + 3_{2} + 2x_{3} + 3x_{4} + 10x_{5} = 0\\ x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 3x_{3} + 4x_{4} + 5x_{5} = \frac{dx_{5}}{dt}\end{cases}$

I hope to impose the normalization condition that $|x_{1}|^2+|x_{2}|^2+|x_{4}|^2$=1 for all time. This is, however, not an initial condition.

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

When I try to add the normalization condition as part of the DAEs equations, the error is:

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of
>   inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used
>   by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of
>   the system may help. >> DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the
>   general solution, unable to solve the conditions. >>

(Note: The above set of differential equations is just arbitrary, may not be consistent or solvable.)

Comment: Please post Mathematica code, not TeX. Thanks

Comment: Also, please do not use subscripts here.  They add needless complexity.  Instead, use `x1` etc.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{0, 0, 5, 3, 3}, {5, 5, 5, 3, 1}, {0, 3, 0, 3, 10}, {1, 3, 2, 3, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
vars = {x1@t, x2@t, x3@t, x4@t, x5@t};
normeq = x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + x4[t]^2 == 1; 
eq = Thread[a.vars == {x1'[t], 0, x3'[t], 0, x5'[t]}];
sol = DSolve[eq, vars, t];
cs = Solve[normeq /. sol, {C[1], C[2], C[3]}];
k = vars /. sol /. cs[[1]] /. C[_] :> 0 // N;
Plot[{k, Norm[{k[[1, 1]], k[[1, 2]], k[[1, 4]]}]}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where you can see the `normeq` is satisfied as requested

Comment: Thank you very much. Do C[1],C[2],C[3] mean the constants in the solution in differential equations? After cs = Solve[normeq /. sol, {C[1], C[2], C[3]}], I get only the solution of C[3] in terms of C[1] and C[2]. Can you tell me what k means? Thanks

Comment: @kwyip Yep. The Cs are those constants. `k` means nothing, it's just a holding var for the ODE results

Comment: Does the line "k = vars /. sol /. cs[[1]] /. C[_] :> 0 // N;" mean setting C[1], C[2] and C[3] to zero? and does the line "Plot[{k, Norm[{k[[1, 1]], k[[1, 2]], k[[1, 4]]}]}, {t, 0, 2}]" mean plotting k, x1, x2, x3, x4 and x5 versus time? Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder how to assign values to the constants C[1],C[2] and C[3]. I try with C[1] = 1 but it fails (with the reason (I get the warnings like Set::write: Tag C in C[1] is Protected. >> )

Comment: @kwyip You still need to learn the very basics. Do this `yourExpression /. C[1]->0` and then search the docs for `ReplaceAll[]`

Comment: One more follow-up question: Is abs(x1[t])^2 the same as x1[t]^2 in mathematica? If I do abs(x1[t])^2, this error shows up: "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the \
system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present \
in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact \
input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help"