# What particular situation do we have to use RuleDelayed after replacement?

Tags: replacement

On the answer of [How to impose normalization condition (not initial condition) on DSolve or NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75335/how-to-impose-normalization-condition-not-initial-condition-on-dsolve-or-ndsol)

```
k = vars /. sol /. cs[[1]] /. C[_] :> 0 // N;
```

I see that in the documentation of ReplaceAll and examples of ReplaceAll on the internet, we use Rule (->) instead of RuleDelayed(:>) after ReplaceAll (/.). I don't understand why RuleDelayed has to be used in the above answer.

Using rule:

```
k = vars /. sol /. cs[[1]] /. C[_] -> 0 // N;
```

can get the plots I want. But there must be something requiring the use of RuleDelayed in the above answer. What is this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: As your own testing confirms, you can use either `Rule` or `RuleDelayed` in that particular case.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what might be considered a classic example of the difference. Suppose I have a list containing a number of `x`s and maybe some other elements, and I want to replace the  `x`s with random integers in some range, but I want new random draw for each replacement.

```
SeedRandom[42]; {x, y, x, x, y} /. x -> RandomInteger[9]
```

> ```
> {6, y, 6, 6, y}
> ```

doesn't work  because `RandomInteger` only get called once, before any replacements are made. However,

```
SeedRandom[42]; {x, y, x, x, y} /. x :> RandomInteger[9]
```

> ```
> {6, y, 0, 8, y}
> ```

works just fine because the rule evaluation is delayed and only made when the rule is used. See [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)